# Dia add existing class to package

Tags: uml, dia

I'm using the [Dia](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Dia) diagram editor to create an UML for a project, and I want to add a class into a package. This can be easily done when the class is created, then the class and the package are bound and the class can't be moved outside the package.
But I have designed many of my classes outside of a package and nom I want to add them in a package, and I can't figure out how to add a pre-existing class to a package.

Am I missing something ? Any ideas ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well I found it, it's in the menu Objects > Adopt.

Comment: In the version I have this command is called "parent", and is only available if the object to be added to a container is placed over top of the container, and both the object and container are selected.

Comment: The object must also not already have a parent (unparent it first if it does).

Comment: @tremby I'm having the same issue as the OP, and I've tried your method, but it doesn't seem to work for me. Should the contained object be completely covering the container, or should they just be touching? I can't figure out how to make a package _adopt_ a class.

Comment: I don't remember in detail, but in my cases I always had the inner object completely surrounded by the outer, and above (i.e. visible on top). Then if memory serves I selected both, and chose objects -> parent.